# Keydown event does not work

Tags: jquery

I made a search code in Jquery and I want it to "link" the user to the city that he is typing if he hits enter (when the whole name of the city is typed) and I also want It to take him if he clicks on the result bar.

I have this code that everything works in it instead when i tried to put the "hit on enter" function, that won't work.

**EDITED**: Now it will redirect me to the last city i have in my Json file, instead of redirect me to the city im typing

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  $('#result1').html('');
  $('#state').val('');
  var searchField = $('#search_text').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 || value.location.search(expression) != -1)
    {
     $('#result1').append('<li class="list-group-item "> <a href="'+value.link+'"> '+value.name+' | <span class="text-muted">'+value.location+'</span></li> </a>');
    }
     $('#search_text').keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.which === 13) {
            window.location.href = value.link;
          }
        });
   });   
  });
 });

 $('#result1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
  $('#search_text').val($.trim(click_text[0]));
  $("#result1").html('');
 });
});
```

Comment: Maybe try adding e.preventDefault();

Comment: what error do you see in `console` ?

Comment: Your result click is outside the document.ready as one can see if one formats the code correctly

Comment: @mplungjan It is inside the bracket "}". I don't understand what you mean when you say "format".

Comment: I created a snippet and clicked TIDY. You will see your last code is OUTSIDE the end  }) of the document.ready - delete the }) before the `$('#result1').on(...`

Comment: Also you have `// ### this is the code that won't work ###
        $('#search_text').keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.which === 13) {
            window.location.href = value.link;
          }
        });
        // #############################################` inside the each. instead of where you have your keyup code. Please fix the code to reflect your actual code

Comment: ok so now i deleted that and now it seems like there is no error on the console @mplungja . But I have several cities and it won't redirect me to the correct city

Comment: @UsmanRana ok now i have a different problem as i Edited the question

Comment: @SamLittlefair where should i add this?

Comment: try logging your json in console. also `value.link`

Comment: There's no error in the console.

Comment: @mplungjani edited the code, now it will get the last city in the Json file

Answer (score 0):

Does your listener for the keydown have to be inside the getJSON and .each loop? 
This also causes it to get attached each time through the loop. If you must have it inside the loop (doesn't look it needs to be there), use this instead:

$("#search_text").unbind('keydown').keydown(...)

Try placing it outside the loop and see what happens next. Some console.log messages to see if the event is even firing can be helpful, too.